# Treeview inside getChildern()

Tags: java, treeview, rcp, emf

Is it possible to create a treeview inside the getChildern() method of the content provider?

I have a treeview whose getElements() method show some nodes coming from an enum for each node in this tree I want to have another tree view. So when the user expand one root node another tree view should be there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot nest tree viewers. You must use a data model for the tree that represents the whole tree.

Suppose you have a class `TopLevelElement` representing one of the top level elements in the tree, and classes `Level1Element` and `Level2Element` for the first and second level children. Then your content provider methods would be something like:

```
@Override
public Object [] getElements(Object inputElement)
{
  return array of TopLevelElements object;
}

@Override
public Object [] getChildren(Object parentElement)
{
  if (parentElement instanceof TopLevelElement)
   {
     return array of Level1Element children of the top level element
   }
  else if (parentElement instanceof Level1Element)
   {
     return array of Level2Element children of Level1Element
   }
  else if (parentElement instanceof Level2Element)
   { 
     ... return any level 3 elements
   }

  return new Object[0];  // Unknown tree element
}
```

Comment: My problem is that the parent element is an enum literal :(

Comment: level 1 elements are components and level 2 are sub-components , while the the level is not known i-e the sub-components can have more sub-components and so on...

Comment: You don't need to know the level, just how to get the children of the 'parentElement' you are given.

Comment: Can we talk in chat please?

Comment: Thank you so much ... you always come to save my life :)